# Crackling sound about every second on headphones (Steelseries) when audio starts. Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, sound, pulseaudio, soundcard

**Summary**

Device: Steelseries Arctis 5.
Sound is fine on any other device.
The Steelseries headphones doesn't affected by this issue on Windows 11.
Both Steelseries Game/Chat outputs are affected by this issue.
Doesn't matter if I play the sound is on the browser or download.
When you increase volume, the crackling is also became louder.

**What have been done:**

- Disabled the power saving extension in the pulseaudio config: commented `load-module module-suspend-on-idle` in this `/etc/pulse/default.pa`
- Turned off sound card power-saving capabilities: `/sys/module/snd_hda_intel/parameters/power_save` and `/sys/module/snd_hda_intel/parameters/power_save_controller`
- Updated `load-module module-udev-detect` to `load-module module-udev-detect tsched=0` in `/etc/pulse/default.pa`
- Changed `; default-fragments` and `; default-fragment-size-msec` in `/etc/pulse/daemon.conf`  to 3 and 5 accordingly [(PulseAudio Troobleshooting)](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/PulseAudio/Troubleshooting)
- Changed `default-sample-rate` to 48000 in `/etc/pulse/daemon.conf`
- And some other tweaks that also had no effect

**My current settings:**

**1.** `pactl list sinks` (Sink 1 and Sink 2 affected):

```
Sink #0
    State: IDLE
    Name: alsa_output.pci-0000_01_00.1.hdmi-stereo
    Description: GM204 High Definition Audio Controller Digital Stereo (HDMI)
    Driver: module-alsa-card.c
    Sample Specification: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
    Channel Map: front-left,front-right
    Owner Module: 6
    Mute: no
    Volume: front-left: 41944 /  64% / -11,63 dB,   front-right: 41944 /  64% / -11,63 dB
            balance 0,00
    Base Volume: 65536 / 100% / 0,00 dB
    Monitor Source: alsa_output.pci-0000_01_00.1.hdmi-stereo.monitor
    Latency: 100134 usec, configured 100136 usec
    Flags: HARDWARE DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY SET_FORMATS 
    Properties:
        alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
        device.api = "alsa"
        device.class = "sound"
        alsa.class = "generic"
        alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
        alsa.name = "HDMI 0"
        alsa.id = "HDMI 0"
        alsa.subdevice = "0"
        alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
        alsa.device = "3"
        alsa.card = "2"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA NVidia"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA NVidia at 0x91080000 irq 17"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:01:00.1"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card2"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "10de"
        device.vendor.name = "NVIDIA Corporation"
        device.product.id = "0fbb"
        device.product.name = "GM204 High Definition Audio Controller"
        device.string = "hdmi:2"
        device.buffering.buffer_size = "17664"
        device.buffering.fragment_size = "2944"
        device.access_mode = "mmap"
        device.profile.name = "hdmi-stereo"
        device.profile.description = "Digital Stereo (HDMI)"
        device.description = "GM204 High Definition Audio Controller Digital Stereo (HDMI)"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    Ports:
        hdmi-output-0: HDMI / DisplayPort (priority: 5900, available)
    Active Port: hdmi-output-0
    Formats:
        pcm

Sink #1
    State: IDLE
    Name: alsa_output.usb-SteelSeries_SteelSeries_Arctis_5_00000000-00.analog-chat
    Description: SteelSeries Arctis 5 Chat
    Driver: module-alsa-card.c
    Sample Specification: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
    Channel Map: front-left,front-right
    Owner Module: 7
    Mute: no
    Volume: front-left: 31609 /  48% / -19,00 dB,   front-right: 31609 /  48% / -19,00 dB
            balance 0,00
    Base Volume: 54094 /  83% / -5,00 dB
    Monitor Source: alsa_output.usb-SteelSeries_SteelSeries_Arctis_5_00000000-00.analog-chat.monitor
    Latency: 105438 usec, configured 99954 usec
    Flags: HARDWARE HW_MUTE_CTRL HW_VOLUME_CTRL DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY 
    Properties:
        alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
        device.api = "alsa"
        device.class = "sound"
        alsa.class = "generic"
        alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
        alsa.name = "USB Audio"
        alsa.id = "USB Audio"
        alsa.subdevice = "0"
        alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
        alsa.device = "0"
        alsa.card = "1"
        alsa.card_name = "SteelSeries Arctis 5"
        alsa.long_card_name = "SteelSeries SteelSeries Arctis 5 at usb-0000:00:14.0-10, full speed"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_usb_audio"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:10:1.0"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-10/1-10:1.0/sound/card1"
        udev.id = "usb-SteelSeries_SteelSeries_Arctis_5_00000000-00"
        device.bus = "usb"
        device.vendor.id = "1038"
        device.vendor.name = "SteelSeries ApS"
        device.product.id = "1250"
        device.product.name = "SteelSeries Arctis 5"
        device.serial = "SteelSeries_SteelSeries_Arctis_5_00000000"
        device.string = "hw:1,0,0"
        device.buffering.buffer_size = "17632"
        device.buffering.fragment_size = "4408"
        device.access_mode = "mmap"
        device.profile.name = "analog-chat"
        device.profile.description = "Chat"
        device.intended_roles = "phone"
        device.description = "SteelSeries Arctis 5 Chat"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-usb"
    Ports:
        steelseries-arctis-output-chat-common: steelseries-arctis-output-chat-common (priority: 5000)
    Active Port: steelseries-arctis-output-chat-common
    Formats:
        pcm

Sink #2
    State: IDLE
    Name: alsa_output.usb-SteelSeries_SteelSeries_Arctis_5_00000000-00.analog-game
    Description: SteelSeries Arctis 5 Game
    Driver: module-alsa-card.c
    Sample Specification: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
    Channel Map: front-left,front-right
    Owner Module: 7
    Mute: no
    Volume: front-left: 11796 /  18% / -44,68 dB,   front-right: 11796 /  18% / -44,68 dB
            balance 0,00
    Base Volume: 54094 /  83% / -5,00 dB
    Monitor Source: alsa_output.usb-SteelSeries_SteelSeries_Arctis_5_00000000-00.analog-game.monitor
    Latency: 102580 usec, configured 99954 usec
    Flags: HARDWARE HW_MUTE_CTRL HW_VOLUME_CTRL DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY 
    Properties:
        alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
        device.api = "alsa"
        device.class = "sound"
        alsa.class = "generic"
        alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
        alsa.name = "USB Audio #1"
        alsa.id = "USB Audio"
        alsa.subdevice = "0"
        alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
        alsa.device = "1"
        alsa.card = "1"
        alsa.card_name = "SteelSeries Arctis 5"
        alsa.long_card_name = "SteelSeries SteelSeries Arctis 5 at usb-0000:00:14.0-10, full speed"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_usb_audio"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:10:1.0"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-10/1-10:1.0/sound/card1"
        udev.id = "usb-SteelSeries_SteelSeries_Arctis_5_00000000-00"
        device.bus = "usb"
        device.vendor.id = "1038"
        device.vendor.name = "SteelSeries ApS"
        device.product.id = "1250"
        device.product.name = "SteelSeries Arctis 5"
        device.serial = "SteelSeries_SteelSeries_Arctis_5_00000000"
        device.string = "hw:1,1,0"
        device.buffering.buffer_size = "17632"
        device.buffering.fragment_size = "4408"
        device.access_mode = "mmap"
        device.profile.name = "analog-game"
        device.profile.description = "Game"
        device.description = "SteelSeries Arctis 5 Game"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-usb"
    Ports:
        steelseries-arctis-output-game-common: steelseries-arctis-output-game-common (priority: 9900)
    Active Port: steelseries-arctis-output-game-common
    Formats:
        pcm

Sink #4
    State: IDLE
    Name: alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo
    Description: Built-in Audio Analog Stereo
    Driver: module-alsa-card.c
    Sample Specification: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
    Channel Map: front-left,front-right
    Owner Module: 8
    Mute: no
    Volume: front-left: 28914 /  44% / -21,32 dB,   front-right: 28914 /  44% / -21,32 dB
            balance 0,00
    Base Volume: 65536 / 100% / 0,00 dB
    Monitor Source: alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo.monitor
    Latency: 100566 usec, configured 99954 usec
    Flags: HARDWARE HW_MUTE_CTRL HW_VOLUME_CTRL DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY 
    Properties:
        alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
        device.api = "alsa"
        device.class = "sound"
        alsa.class = "generic"
        alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
        alsa.name = "ALC1220 Analog"
        alsa.id = "ALC1220 Analog"
        alsa.subdevice = "0"
        alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
        alsa.device = "0"
        alsa.card = "0"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel PCH"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel PCH at 0x4012110000 irq 162"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1f.3"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "8086"
        device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
        device.product.id = "06c8"
        device.form_factor = "internal"
        device.string = "front:0"
        device.buffering.buffer_size = "17632"
        device.buffering.fragment_size = "4408"
        device.access_mode = "mmap"
        device.profile.name = "analog-stereo"
        device.profile.description = "Analog Stereo"
        device.description = "Built-in Audio Analog Stereo"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    Ports:
        analog-output-lineout: Line Out (priority: 9000, not available)
        analog-output-headphones: Headphones (priority: 9900, not available)
    Active Port: analog-output-headphones
    Formats:
        pcm
```

**2.** `/etc/pulse/default.pa`

```
#!/usr/bin/pulseaudio -nF
#
# This file is part of PulseAudio.
#
# PulseAudio is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it
# under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by
# the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or
# (at your option) any later version.
#
# PulseAudio is distributed in the hope that it will be useful, but
# WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
# MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. See the GNU
# General Public License for more details.
#
# You should have received a copy of the GNU Lesser General Public License
# along with PulseAudio; if not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.

# This startup script is used only if PulseAudio is started per-user
# (i.e. not in system mode)

.fail

### Automatically restore the volume of streams and devices
load-module module-device-restore
load-module module-stream-restore
load-module module-card-restore

### Automatically augment property information from .desktop files
### stored in /usr/share/application
load-module module-augment-properties

### Should be after module-*-restore but before module-*-detect
# load-module module-switch-on-port-available

### Use hot-plugged devices like Bluetooth or USB automatically (LP: #1702794)
.ifexists module-switch-on-connect.so
load-module module-switch-on-connect
.endif

### Load audio drivers statically
### (it's probably better to not load these drivers manually, but instead
### use module-udev-detect -- see below -- for doing this automatically)
#load-module module-alsa-sink
#load-module module-alsa-source device=hw:1,0
#load-module module-oss device="/dev/dsp" sink_name=output source_name=input
#load-module module-oss-mmap device="/dev/dsp" sink_name=output source_name=input
#load-module module-null-sink
#load-module module-pipe-sink

### Automatically load driver modules depending on the hardware available
.ifexists module-udev-detect.so
load-module module-udev-detect tsched=0
.else
### Use the static hardware detection module (for systems that lack udev support)
load-module module-detect tsched=0
.endif

### Automatically connect sink and source if JACK server is present
.ifexists module-jackdbus-detect.so
.nofail
load-module module-jackdbus-detect channels=2
.fail
.endif

### Automatically load driver modules for Bluetooth hardware
.ifexists module-bluetooth-policy.so
load-module module-bluetooth-policy
.endif

.ifexists module-bluetooth-discover.so
load-module module-bluetooth-discover
.endif

### Load several protocols
.ifexists module-esound-protocol-unix.so
load-module module-esound-protocol-unix
.endif
load-module module-native-protocol-unix

### Network access (may be configured with paprefs, so leave this commented
### here if you plan to use paprefs)
#load-module module-esound-protocol-tcp
#load-module module-native-protocol-tcp
#load-module module-zeroconf-publish

### Load the RTP receiver module (also configured via paprefs, see above)
#load-module module-rtp-recv

### Load the RTP sender module (also configured via paprefs, see above)
#load-module module-null-sink sink_name=rtp format=s16be channels=2 rate=44100 sink_properties="device.description='RTP Multicast Sink'"
#load-module module-rtp-send source=rtp.monitor

### Load additional modules from GSettings. This can be configured with the paprefs tool.
### Please keep in mind that the modules configured by paprefs might conflict with manually
### loaded modules.
.ifexists module-gsettings.so
.nofail
load-module module-gsettings
.fail
.endif


### Automatically restore the default sink/source when changed by the user
### during runtime
### NOTE: This should be loaded as early as possible so that subsequent modules
### that look up the default sink/source get the right value
load-module module-default-device-restore

### Make sure we always have a sink around, even if it is a null sink.
load-module module-always-sink

### Honour intended role device property
load-module module-intended-roles

### Automatically suspend sinks/sources that become idle for too long
# load-module module-suspend-on-idle

### If autoexit on idle is enabled we want to make sure we only quit
### when no local session needs us anymore.
.ifexists module-console-kit.so
load-module module-console-kit
.endif
.ifexists module-systemd-login.so
load-module module-systemd-login
.endif

### Enable positioned event sounds
load-module module-position-event-sounds

### Cork music/video streams when a phone stream is active
load-module module-role-cork

### Block audio recording for snap confined packages unless they have
### the "pulseaudio" or "audio-record" interfaces plugged.
.ifexists module-snap-policy.so
load-module module-snap-policy
.endif

### Modules to allow autoloading of filters (such as echo cancellation)
### on demand. module-filter-heuristics tries to determine what filters
### make sense, and module-filter-apply does the heavy-lifting of
### loading modules and rerouting streams.
load-module module-filter-heuristics
load-module module-filter-apply

### Make some devices default
#set-default-sink output
#set-default-source input
```

**3.** `/etc/pulse/daemon.conf`

```
# This file is part of PulseAudio.
#
# PulseAudio is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
# it under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by
# the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or
# (at your option) any later version.
#
# PulseAudio is distributed in the hope that it will be useful, but
# WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
# MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. See the GNU
# General Public License for more details.
#
# You should have received a copy of the GNU Lesser General Public License
# along with PulseAudio; if not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.

## Configuration file for the PulseAudio daemon. See pulse-daemon.conf(5) for
## more information. Default values are commented out.  Use either ; or # for
## commenting.

; daemonize = no
; fail = yes
; allow-module-loading = yes
; allow-exit = yes
; use-pid-file = yes
; system-instance = no
; local-server-type = user
; enable-shm = yes
; enable-memfd = yes
; shm-size-bytes = 0 # setting this 0 will use the system-default, usually 64 MiB
; lock-memory = no
; cpu-limit = no

; high-priority = yes
; nice-level = -11

; realtime-scheduling = yes
; realtime-priority = 5

; exit-idle-time = 20
; scache-idle-time = 20

; dl-search-path = (depends on architecture)

; load-default-script-file = yes
; default-script-file = /etc/pulse/default.pa

; log-target = auto
; log-level = notice
; log-meta = no
; log-time = no
; log-backtrace = 0

; resample-method = speex-float-1
; avoid-resampling = yes
; enable-remixing = yes
; remixing-use-all-sink-channels = yes
; remixing-produce-lfe = no
; remixing-consume-lfe = no
; lfe-crossover-freq = 0

; flat-volumes = no

; rescue-streams = yes

; rlimit-fsize = -1
; rlimit-data = -1
; rlimit-stack = -1
; rlimit-core = -1
; rlimit-as = -1
; rlimit-rss = -1
; rlimit-nproc = -1
; rlimit-nofile = 256
; rlimit-memlock = -1
; rlimit-locks = -1
; rlimit-sigpending = -1
; rlimit-msgqueue = -1
; rlimit-nice = 31
; rlimit-rtprio = 9
; rlimit-rttime = 200000

; default-sample-format = s16le
; default-sample-rate = 44100
; alternate-sample-rate = 48000
; default-sample-channels = 2
; default-channel-map = front-left,front-right

; default-fragments = 4
; default-fragment-size-msec = 25

; enable-deferred-volume = yes
deferred-volume-safety-margin-usec = 1
; deferred-volume-extra-delay-usec = 0
```

Comment: @Nmath, Done: [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/1966132)

Comment: What kernel are you running? I just started noticing this issue with my Steelseries Arctis 5 on Ubuntu 21.10 a few days ago. I just remembered tonight that my system was updated to kernel 5.13.0-37-generic a few days ago, so I rolled back to 5.13.0-35-generic to see if that would fix the problem, and it seems like that fixed it for me.

Comment: Thank you @BenM I had exactly what you described. My kernel was 5.13.0-37-generic and after downgrading to 5.13.0-35-generic looks like the issue is gone. Can you repeat your comment as an answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What kernel are you running? I just started noticing this issue with my Steelseries Arctis 5 on Ubuntu 21.10 a few days ago. I just remembered tonight that my system was updated to kernel 5.13.0-37-generic a few days ago, so I rolled back to 5.13.0-35-generic to see if that would fix the problem, and it seems like that fixed it for me.

Comment: Thank you again for this solution. This really helped.

Comment: Happy I could help :)

Answer (score 2):

For me setting the default sample rate of pulse audio to 48000 did the trick, as it is described in this [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-signed-hwe-5.13/+bug/1966066)

1. open `/etc/pulse/daemon.conf` and change default-sample-rate to 48000. **Dont forget to remove the semicolon at the beginning of the line**.
2. Restart pulse with: `systemctl --user restart pulseaudio.service`

Comment: Oh, I've tried this solution before asking the question here, but I forgot to remove the semicolons! Tried this workaround on 5.13.0-39-generic and it worked for me.

Comment: Amazing, this seems to have worked for me as well. Thanks again.