# Cracking sound problem in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: sound, 22.04

Whenever I plug in earphone in my laptop while using ubuntu always cracking sound is present in the earphone while I also have windows in my laptop no problem there. How to fix this?
I am using lenovo thinkbook laptop

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Crackling sound about every second on headphones (Steelseries) when audio starts. Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1398966/crackling-sound-about-every-second-on-headphones-steelseries-when-audio-starts)

Comment: I'm having the very same problem with a new ThinkBook 13s. [Others have, too](https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/rn1nle/thinkbook_13s_g2_intel_headphones_background/). I'm tempted to try [the options suggested here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1316745/no-sound-on-ubuntu-20-04-lenovo-thinkbook-14s-g2), but don't want to bork my system.