# Headphone with single 3.5mm jack Mic not working on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, microphone, headphones, headset

I have HP Pavilion 15-aw020ca Laptop with a single headphone connector meant for headphone with 3.5mm jack. I initially had problems with the headphone but after trying different things (based on my research on the internet) I was able to get the headphone(speaker) part working fine but the microphone part remains a problem. Below is a configuration of my /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf file:

```
options snd-hda-intel model=headset-mode
options snd-hda-intel model=auto,dell-headset-multi
options snd-hda-intel model=alc295-eapd
options snd-hda-intel model=alc295-hp-x360
```

Below is a screenshot of the configuration of my hdajackretask
[hda jack retasking image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OyH8u.png)

Below is a screenshot of my sound settings
[sound settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OmA9f.png)

From the image above, the headset microphone is detected but not working. I used the PulseAudio to check it. It was on the list of devices but "unpluged". Below is an image of it.

[PulseAudio image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EGShd.png)

Please I really need help as I have been trying different things since the past 2 days. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the solution. I just changed the default sample rate of pulse audio to 48000 and that was it. MAGICAL!!! Thanks to this post
[Crackling sound about every second on headphones (Steelseries) when audio starts. Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1398966/crackling-sound-about-every-second-on-headphones-steelseries-when-audio-starts)